Sysprep - ExtendOSPartition - unattend
At the moment I'm running:
Sysprep.exe /generalize /oobe /quit /mode:vm /quiet

Which works fine.
I'm now trying to add /unattend to be able to include configuration for ExtendOSPartition.
What I have right now is the following unattend.xml file:
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="generalize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-PnpSysprep" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Generalize>
                <Mode>OOBE</Mode>
            </Generalize>
            <ExtendOSPartition>
                <Extend>true</Extend>
            </ExtendOSPartition>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>

And then I try to run sysprep
Sysprep.exe /generalize /oobe /quit /mode:vm /unattend:"C:\post-generation\unattend.xml" /quiet

I've tried various configurations for the unattend.xml file, but none of them seem to work. The current unattend.xml presents the following error:
2024-04-10 15:59:09, Info                         [Sysprep.exe] UnattendFindAnswerFile: Looking at explicitly provided unattend file [C:\post-generation\unattend.xml]...
2024-04-10 15:59:09, Info                         [Sysprep.exe] UnattendFindAnswerFile: [C:\post-generation\unattend.xml] meets criteria for an explicitly provided unattend file.
2024-04-10 15:59:09, Info                  SYSPRP SysprepSearchForUnattend: Using unattend file at [C:\post-generation\unattend.xml].
2024-04-10 15:59:09, Warning               SYSPRP SysprepSearchForUnattend: Unattend file [C:\post-generation\unattend.xml] contains invalid [generalize] pass; hrResult = 0x80220003
2024-04-10 15:59:09, Warning               SYSPRP WinMain:Encountered invalid unattend file during search; hrResult = 0x80220003
2024-04-10 15:59:09, Info                  IBS    UnattendErrorFromResults: Hit an unattend error; dumping any info we have about the failure...
2024-04-10 15:59:09, Info                  IBS    UnattendDumpSetting: ------Unattend setting error / warning------
2024-04-10 15:59:09, Info                  IBS    UnattendDumpSetting: Error code = 0x80220003
2024-04-10 15:59:09, Info                  IBS    UnattendDumpSetting: Pass = generalize
2024-04-10 15:59:09, Info                  IBS    UnattendDumpSetting: --------------------------------------------
2024-04-10 15:59:09, Info                  IBS    UnattendErrorFromResults: Error text = Windows could not parse or process the unattend answer file for pass [generalize]. The answer file is invalid.

What I want to achieve, is the exact same results as when I'm running this:
Sysprep.exe /generalize /oobe /quit /mode:vm /quiet

But I also want it to extend the OS partition upon the first boot.
I've never used or configured an unattend.xml file before, so I apologize if I'm lacking basic stuff.
UPDATE
Now I've also tried this:
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
            <ExtendOSPartition>true</ExtendOSPartition>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>

Which writes IMAGE_STATE_UNDEPLOYABLE to: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\State
Also it writes this to the setuperr.log:
2024-03-02 18:24:32, Error                 SYSPRP MRTGeneralize:98 - ERROR: Failed ConnectServer
2024-03-02 18:24:34, Error                 SYSPRP BCD: BiUpdateEfiEntry failed c000000d
2024-03-02 18:24:34, Error                 SYSPRP BCD: BiExportBcdObjects failed c000000d
2024-03-02 18:24:34, Error                 SYSPRP BCD: BiExportStoreAlterationsToEfi failed c000000d
2024-03-02 18:24:34, Error                 SYSPRP BCD: Failed to export alterations to firmware. Status: c000000d

And seemingly corrupts the VM, since I can't connect to it regularly anymore (got the log via the serial console).

ExtendOSPartition is located under Microsoft-Windows-Deployment, not Microsoft-Windows-Setup. Make sure your source image doesn't have a recovery partition in front of the OS partition. Consider using windows SIM to generate unattend.xml files

Will try to change to Microsoft-Windows-Deployment and also look at Windows SIM, was not aware of that tool. Thanks for taking your time and provide input.

Thank you for pointing out that it was located under Microsoft-Windows-Deployment, it made me revisit the documentation and got me going!

This did the trick and worked for my needs:
unattend.xml:
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ExtendOSPartition>
                <Extend>true</Extend>
            </ExtendOSPartition>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>

sysprep command line:
Sysprep.exe /generalize /oobe /quit /mode:vm /unattend:"C:\unattend.xml" /quiet

